# Euler cycles in biconnected components

Tags: graphs, eulerian-paths

If a graph has a Euler cycle, do the biconnected components have Euler cycles as well?

Comment: If this is a homework problem, perhaps its best for you to try it on your own?

A graph may have a Euler Cycle, but it doesnt seem to follow naturally that a subset (even a biconnected one) should.
Have you tried comming up with a counter example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  If you start with a Euler cycle for the graph and restrict to a biconnected component, then what you have is still a cycle on the biconnected component (basically, if the euler cycle leaves vertex v in the biconnected component, then you know it must return to the biconnected component through v, otherwise we could enlarge our biconnected component - contradicting its maximality).